# Get href when iframe is inside multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to get the page in which my iframe is loaded.

However my iframe is sometimes loaded inside an iframe which itself is loaded inside another iframe.

like this:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <iframe src="site_a">
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <iframe src="mysite"></iframe>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If in the head of "mysite" I try window.top.location.href I get cross-origin errors.

```
      <script>
     (function(){

        var url = window.top.location.href;
        console.log(url);
     })();
     </script>
```

gives

```
  Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "mysite" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

How could I get the actual url in the browser bar so I can see on which pages someone loads my iframe?

Comment: Please share some code or set a pen and share.

Comment: @pixellab done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I get the actual url in the browser bar so I can see on which pages someone loads my iframe?

You can't.

> I get cross-origin errors.

And that is why.

Your JavaScript is not allowed to monitor what people do on other websites, even if those other websites put your page in a frame.

Comment: I don't need to monitor what people do on the other site. I just want to check if the owner of site_a says he displays me on site x it actually is on site x and not y

Comment: And to do that you need to know what URL the visitor is visiting … on another site … which is something they are doing on another site.

Comment: Okay don't understand how this is a security risk, but I guess I'll have to accept it. Thanks for the anwser.